# WCF: Do I have to listen to Channel.Faulted events if I am using ChannelFactory and creatingchannel for each operation

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client

I am creating channel everytime before performing an operation on service using ChannelFactory.CreateChannel(). At the end of the operation I will close the channel or abort it if there are any exceptions.

Since I am creating a channel each time, do I have to listen to "Faulted" events.

Btw, why channelFactory has Faulted event, when all the stuff is done by the channel.

Or - will be it raised when any of the channels created by this factory faulted?

Thanks in advance,
Dreamer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason I would listen to the Faulted event is if I wanted to do something particular if the event occurs (other than aborting the channel).  I can't, off the top of my head, think of a reason to use it - but that doesn't mean there isn't one.

In your case, if you're aborting the channel when an error occurs, then you're fine - you don't ned to handle the Faulted event.

[`FactoryChannel<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132.aspx) implements [ICommunicationObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.icommunicationobject.aspx), which defines a faulted event.  MSDN says "Defines the contract for the basic state machine for all communication-oriented objects in the system, including channels, the channel managers, ***factories***, listeners, and dispatchers, and service hosts."

[`FactoryChannel<T>.CreateChannel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms575250.aspx) returns a type of [IChannel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.ichannel.aspx), which also implements ICommunicationObject.

Comment: So they are the same? (Sorry, if the question sounds stupid but I really don't get it :-) )